# galleria Slideshow images does not display

Tags: nodes

I have created an eva view, to display a group of gallery albums. Within my content type on manage displays am using a default galleria formatter and in my eva view I have a Grid of different image albums.
All I get is the album thumbnails. Tried to clear the cache but still.
I went through the galleria read me, and I believe I have done everything that they said one needs to do to get galleria working.

I am using Drupal 7 and have installed the followings:

Initially installed
Galleria Jquery plugin(libraries) 1.4.2
Galleria module (7.x-1.0-beta3)
but didn't work
I then added the following modules
Views Slideshow: 7.x-3.1
Views Slideshow: Galleria: 7.x-3.2

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for browsing my question.
I got it right by simply reverting back to an old version of Galleria Jquery plugin. I used galleria 1.2.9 instead of 1.4.2 and all is well.

I am still puzzled though as to why the new version is not working.